# Is there an additional reward for completing all bounties in all acts in a single game?

Tags: diablo-iii

Compared to, for example, completing 5 bounties in each of 5 different games.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer used to be no, but [Patch 2.3](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19859662/patch-230-now-live-8-25-2015#am) has changed this.

When you start a game in Adventure Mode, a single act will be marked as a Bonus Act.  Completing all bounties in that act will award you with a Bonus Cache, similar to the Horadric Cache you normally get.  The Bonus Cache will contain gold, blood shards, and crafting materials, including the new act-specific crafting materials that are required to craft set and legendary pieces.

Once you acquire this Bonus Cache, the Bonus Act changes to one of the other acts in the game.  So by completing all of the bounties in a game, you will obtain the extra gold, blood shards, and act-specific crafting materials - as long as you do the acts in the order they are marked as Bonus.

You could get all this by making five separate games, but there is no guarantee the first Bonus Act will be a different act in each game.  By completing all bounties in a single game, you can guarantee you receive the extra act-specific crafting mats for all acts.

Comment: What extra reward is there for completing these two acts?

Comment: @Arperum twice as many blood shards, IIRC. I just suggested an edit to the answer to clarify this.

Comment: "So it's worth at least doing two acts worth of bounties before making a new game." - not really. There's no difference between doing two bonus acts in a same game and doing two bonus acts each in a new game.

Comment: @ykb: True, but it would be a minor inconvenience to leave a game session and start a new one after clearing only one act's bounties. In theory, completing the ten bounties spread across both Bonus acts before starting a new game session would be more productive, if only slightly so.

Comment: It would be probably be a good idea to leave old answer as a reference, if only to make old comments make sense :-)

Comment: Technically, there's still no **extra** reward for completing all bounties compared to resetting the game and doing just the bonus act. The only thing you get is the guaranteed opportunity to reap the bonus from each act. The bonus itself does not change.