# Adventure Mode Questions

Tags: diablo-iii

1. Does anyone have specific details on what the bonus means next to a couple of the acts in adventure mode?
2. Is there any benefit to completing all of the bounties in all of the acts in a single game in adventure mode? Or should you just do the bonus acts and recreate?

Answer (score 3):

The bonus means you will get twice the amount of [blood shards](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_Shard) from bounties in that act.

There is currently no extra benefit in completing all bounties across all 5 acts.

Answer (score 0):

If Blizzard introduce new bonus, you can check what is the bonus for an act by pointing the exclamation mark above "Bonus"

[image: map sample]

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would try and do all the acts, and the reward looked the same, although I didn't look closely into it. You probably get more blood shards and better XP and gold too.

> When a player chooses a bounty on the map, it doesn't tell them what the rewards will be. The usual rewards are *gold*, *experience*, and a *Bloodshard*. *Horadric Caches* are rewarded for completing all five bounties of an act.

Taken from [here](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Bounties).

There is a question on this SE site, that will answer your question about completing all bounties in all acts. [Additional Reward for Completing All Bounties in All Acts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162043/is-there-an-additional-reward-for-completing-all-bounties-in-all-acts-in-a-singl)